# Component gives type error if it includes image element

Tags: reactjs, typescript, image, tsx

**The Project**

I have a project (React, Typescript, React useContext) that calls an api to fetch information about the episodes of a series, then display the information as cards.

**Current status**

Last time I ran the project, it worked, I deployed it to Heroku, it worked. One month later, after no changes, it doesn´t work either on my local or on heroku, they throw the same error.

**Errors:**

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'medium' of null
at EpisodesList.tsx:21

EpisodesList.tsx:21 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'medium' of null
at EpisodesList.tsx:21

**The Episodelists component**

```html
const EpisodesList = (props: any): JSX.Element => {
    const { episodes, toggleFavAction, favourites, store } = props;
    const { state, dispatch } = store;

    return episodes.map((episode: Episode) => {
        return (
            <div key={episode.id} className="episode-box">
                <section>
                    <img
                        src={episode.image.medium}
                    />
                    <div>{episode.name}</div>
                    <div>
                        Season: {episode.season} Number: {episode.number}
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
        );
    });
};

export default EpisodesList;
```

**The Home page that uses the component**

```html
const Home = () => {
    const { state, dispatch } = React.useContext(Store);

    useEffect(() => {
        state.episodes.length === 0 && fetchDataAction(dispatch);
    });

    const props: EpisodeProps = {
        episodes: state.episodes,
        store: { state, dispatch },
        toggleFavAction,
        favourites: state.favourites,
    };

    return (
        <section className="episode-layout">
            {console.log("props in home return is:", props)}
            <EpisodesList {...props} />
        </section>
    );
};
```

**Console log + what I tried**

Maybe the issue is related to this --> the console.log in the return part shows:

props in home return is: {episodes: Array(0), store: {…}}

props in home return is: {episodes: Array(42), store: {…}}

The weird thing is, if I remove the image element from the Episodelist component, it works without errors, all the data is there (I can see it in the console.log, even the image.medium).

Any ideas why I am suddenly getting these errors and how I can reinsert my image element?

Comment: Can you add the Episode Type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is use conditional rendering for the image.

<img src={episode.image && episode.image.medium} /> or
<img src={episode.image ? episode.image.medium : "some default image"} />

This happens because on initial render the "image" property of "episode" is null and you are trying to access it like that "episode.null.medium" so you need to add a condition that will try to access the "medium" property only when "episode.image" is not null.

Comment: Thank you for the quick and clear answer, this solved the issue.
I wonder though, why I am not getting an error at the initial render for the places where I try to access data from the same object e.g. episode.name or episode.number. I would love to understand this too.

Comment: For that one I'm not on 100% sure but I guess it is because "episode.images" is an object. When React renders a component based on some object values it checks for their 
presence and if the values are not there (not loaded yet) it renders nothing (null) and that does not throw any errors because when the values are loaded React re-renders the component with those values. However, in that case if the value is an object it will throw error because you can't access property of object if that object is null (not loaded yet).